How to search only within a specific part of the HTML in the Elements tab of Developer Tools?
Is it possible to search words only inside certain elements on the html in Developer Tools?
If I Ctrl+f in Developer Tools it performs the search on the entire html and also it automatically scrolls the html to the first element it finds.
This way if I'm interested to find a term only in a certain section of the html I have to scroll back to that area and this is very time consuming for long htmls.

it is also possible to look for text in the HTML code of certain elements in dev tools, without going over the whole web page.

search within the specific HTML element:


right-click on the desired section of the page and select Inspect. this will open the Elements panel with the HTML highlighted for the section.
right-click the same element again and select search within node (or ctrl+f while the node is selected).
this will limit the search to that specific element and its child nodes.


if you're more familiar with CSS selectors or XPath:


go to the Console tab in Developer Tools

use JavaScript commands to find elements, for example:
> $x("//div[@class='classname']") // XPath
> document.querySelectorAll('.classname') // CSS selector




Unfortunately I don't find option to search within node and if I ctrl+f while the node is selected, it stills search in all html. Thank you anyway :)
